# Does Kaminari remote => true wipe out other parameters (like window)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari, paginator

I am using the kaminari paginator and have it paginating an array fine both with and without ajax. I built the app based off the [kaminari example app](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example).

However, I just noticed a problem and am trying to figure out if this is a bug or just misuse on my part.

View:

```
<%= paginate @pgdata, :remote => true, :window => 2 %>
```

On initial page load, everything is fine, including the next/previous 2 numbered pages displaying (as per :window => 2).  When you click next, previous, first, last or any numbered page, however, it 'forgets' the window setting and reverts to a default of 4.  Changing the default is not an option for me as I need to use different window settings in different situations.

This behavior is not present if remote is removed, the window setting is kept properly.

JS:

```
$('#pglist').html("<%= escape_javascript render 'pglist' %>");
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@pgdata, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

Controller:

```
@pgdata = Kaminari.paginate_array(
      @current_user.somequery
      .sort_by(&:created_at)
      .reverse)
  .page(params[:page])
  .per(10)
```

Rails 4.2.0.  Logs are error free.

Comment: did you try adding the `window: 2` to the controller too ? also why paginate array?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohammad - turns out I figured it out right after posting, I had excluded the window option from the javascript (complete answer below).  As to why paginate an array: why not?  While unrelated to the question, I'm curious if there is a reason I shouldn't.  The 'somedata' method in the example above is actually constructed by adding two ::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxys together - while I tried a few solutions other than the simple addition that results in an array, they all had unintended consequences.

Comment: you should add these default options in the kaminari initializer, would spare you this trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out about 5 minutes after posting the question:  It was misuse on my part. Since I wasted a silly amount of time hunting for the solution to a very simple and obvious mistake, hopefully this will save someone a little frustration.

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@pgdata, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

Needs change to:

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@pgdata, :remote => true, :window => 2).to_s) %>');
```

Since, of course, the JS replaces the <%= paginate ... %> in the view after the first click, you need to add the window setting to the JS paginate as well:

> ", :window => 2"